# WinSCP automatically configure runtime

Tags: scripting, automation, winscp

I have a bastion/jump box providing WinSCP for users to carry out transfers to secured hosts. This is integrated into a privileged access management (PAM) service. I want to automate some behaviours at run time, after the authentication has completed (this is handled by the PAM service) and the application becomes interactive.

While I can define the required actions in a WinSCP extension, I could not see anywhere in the documentation discussing how to run extensions automatically. A fallback would be to provide the user with a button to click on rather than having to dig through the menus to find the extension, but again I don't see this in the docs.

How can I run an extension automatically at the right time?

Comment: This does not look like a question for Server Fault. You should move it to [su].

Comment: I thought about that, however 1) this **is** a question about service provision 2) most people on SuperUser won't understand what Privileges Access Management is.

Comment: But your question is not about PAM, right?

Comment: No, but PAM makes critical changes to the sequence of control. In addition, the question is not about which buttons to poke but how to configure a specific behaviour of the application for all users.

Comment: I do not agree, but anyway, I've tried to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run WinSCP extensions automatically after authentication.

To ease an access, you can display [custom command toolbar](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_toolbars#custom_command):

[image]

(a [WinSCP extension](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension) is just a special kind of a [custom command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_command))